# ExtJS 4.2 - How can I add a table to a panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I´m trying to add this to a panel but I don´t know how:

[image]

This is a table and the container is a panel,and I don´t know how to do this in ExtJS 4.2,because the nearest thing is a grid,but I don´t want a grid.

Comment: You can always put HTML into the [`html` property](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-html).

Comment: I'm trying that,but the blank cells contain dynamic data

Comment: What you want to achieve and what you have tried should be part of your question.

Comment: Did you Try `layout:table` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this with a form panel.
Here is the code:

```
var tabla=new Ext.form.Panel({
    bodyPadding: '0 0 0 0',
    margin:'0 5 0 5',
    bodyStyle: 'background-color:#f1f1f1;',
    border:0,
    items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                anchor: '100%',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items:[
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      labelAlign: 'top',
                                      labelSeparator: '',
                                      fieldLabel: '--',
                                      labelStyle: 'text-align: center;color:#f1f1f1;background-color:#f1f1f1;',
                                      height:104,
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'NUEVO'
                                  }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      labelAlign: 'top',
                                      labelSeparator: '',
                                      fieldLabel: '--',
                                      labelStyle: 'text-align: center;color:#f1f1f1;background-color:#f1f1f1;',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'GANADO',
                                      height:44
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'PERDIDO',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'PENDIENTE',
                                      height:30
                                  }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      labelAlign: 'top',
                                      labelSeparator: '',
                                      fieldLabel: 'VIGOR',
                                      labelStyle: 'text-align: center;background-color:#f1f1f1;',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:44
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'200%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      labelAlign: 'top',
                                      labelSeparator: '',
                                      fieldLabel: 'VENCIDO',
                                      labelStyle: 'text-align: center;background-color:#f1f1f1;',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:44
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  }
                           ]
                       }
                 ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                anchor: '100%',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items:[
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      height:90,
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'MANTENIMIENTO'
                                  }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      value:'GANADO',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'PERDIDO',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;',
                                      value:'PENDIENTE',
                                      height:30
                                  }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'200%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           xtype: 'container',
                           flex: 1,
                           layout: 'anchor',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      margin:'-5 0 0 0',
                                      readOnly:true,
                                      anchor:'100%',
                                      fieldStyle: 'text-align: right;',
                                      height:30
                                  }
                           ]
                       }
                 ]
            }
    ]
});
```

And this is an image of the result:
[image]